# Procedure or function expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, parameters

My source code gives me an error:

> Procedure or function 'spGetImageById' expects parameter '@Photo_ID',
>   which was not supplied.

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spGetImageById]    Script Date: 2018-01-13 18:14:55 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGetImageById]
@Photo_ID int
as
Begin
    Select Photo_Data  
    from tblImages where Photo_ID=@Photo_ID
End
```

Backend code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetImageById", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  

            SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@Photo_ID",
                Value = Request.QueryString["Photo_ID"]
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId);

            con.Open();
            byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            string strBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            Image1.ImageUrl = "data:Image/png;base64," + strBase64;
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

The error occurs in the line:

> "byte[] bytes = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();".

Do you have any idea what's causing the problem? I've lost all hope...

Comment: put a break point on `cmd.Parameters.Add(paramId)`  and inspect `paramId`

Comment: I would give a type to the parameter.

Comment: I think you need the word `exec` in your cmd variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting value from `Request.QueryString["Photo_ID"]` .Try passing hard coded value for testing.

Plus pass parameter a valid `SqlDbType`

```
        SqlParameter paramId = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@Photo_ID",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
            Value = Request.QueryString["Photo_ID"]
        };
```

Comment: Did you tried passing hard coded value to `@Photo_ID`

Comment: Yeah, I did, plus I added the code you suggested but the error is still there.

Comment: Try renaming `@Photo_Id` with `@KeyPhoto`

Comment: Still exact same error message. Maybe there's something wrong with the stored procedure?

Comment: you are getting `@ID` is not supplied ?

Comment: try executing your SP at SQL Server with statement `EXEC spGetImageById @Photo_ID = 10`

Comment: If you suspect something is wrong with the stored procedure, test it independently of your application code.  In fact, you should ensure it works properly before attempting to call it with application code.

Comment: Agree with @DanBracuk

Comment: I thought that stored procedure was fine, it didn't display any errors so thats why I moved forward.

Comment: Executed SP on SQL Server ?

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir yes

Comment: then no issue at code level.You need to re look at your SP

Comment: But the Sql seems to be fine

Comment: Can you share your Exec statement ?

Comment: " Procedure or function 'spGetImageById' expects parameter '@Photo_ID', which was not supplied."

Comment: No , not this , Exec Statement that you ran on SQL Server